# Include null values in JSON (jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin Version-0.4.11)

Tags: json, jsonschema2pojo

When you generate java class using this plugin it applies JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL in genarted class. How to override this default configuration from `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` to
`@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)` in generated class.

I tried putting `<inclusionLevel>ALWAYS</inclusionLevel>` in plugin configuration but it's not working.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until I changed version of jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin to latest 0.5.1 in pom.xml and finally worked. `inclusionLevel` is available since 0.4.30 version.